# Which sites have customized their help center homepage?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, moderator-tools, help-center

I have some ideas for the homepage of the [Web Applications SE Help Center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help); before I start writing the draft I would like to learn from the experiences of other sites. I remember have seeing posts here mentioning sites that have done this but I can only find a couple:

- https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help

I tried searching using combinations of the following:

- [help-center](/questions/tagged/help-center)
- `url:stackexchange.com/help` /  `url:stackoverflow.com/help`
- home-page
- front-page

Related:

- [Is there a place to get the textual overview (what is on-topic) of all sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203463/289691)
- [Which sites have their own blogs?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256202/289691)
- [What parts of the help center can site moderators edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/289691)
- [Improved Help Center - site-specific pages and site-specific edits to all pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279879/289691)
- [Why should the Help Page provide information on the website only?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324742/289691)
- [Is the Help Center content identical on all sites in the Stack Exchange network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331026/289691)

Answer (score 10):

Here is a userscript (a simplified version of [this one here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378658/295232)) which you can run on the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites) to see which sites have altered the Help Center homepage:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Help Center analyzer
// @author      Glorfindel
// @version     0.1
// @match       https://stackexchange.com/sites
// @connect     stackexchange.com
// @connect     *.stackexchange.com
// @connect     *.stackoverflow.com
// @connect     *.superuser.com
// @connect     *.serverfault.com
// @connect     *.askubuntu.com
// @connect     *.mathoverflow.net
// @connect     stackapps.com
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant       GM.xmlHttpRequest
// ==/UserScript==

/* global $ */

(function() {
  'use strict';

  var sites = [];
  $("div.lv-item > a").each(function() {
    sites.push($(this).attr("href"));
  });

  var message = "";
  function process() {
    let URL = sites.pop();
    if (typeof URL == 'undefined') {
      console.log(message);
      return;
    }

    let helpURL = URL + "/help";
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
      method: 'GET',
      url: helpURL,
      onload: function(data) {
        $(data.responseText).find("div.wiki-ph-content").each(function() {
          if ($(this).text() != '') {
            message += "\n" + helpURL;
          }
        });
        process();
      }
    });
  };
  process();
})();
```

The script's output will appear in the browser console and is just a list of URLs. I just did some simple post-processing in a text editor to make it fit the table in the other answer.

Comment: Getting rep for the same script twice seems like double-dipping, eh? :-)

Comment: It's even worse - the script started out [to find all differences between Help Centers across the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331040/295232) - interestingly, I forgot about the custom homepage content, so this question is a perfect complement to that one. And it led to my most famous question on the network: [How can this Stack Exchange site have an animated favicon?](https://superuser.com/q/1484570/442468)

Answer (score 9):

## Sites with a custom Help Center homepage

| Site (Link to per-site Help) | Related per-site meta post |
| --- | --- |
| https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://iot.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://latin.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help |  |
| https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://vi.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://coffee.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help |  |
| https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help |  |
| https://ham.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://mathoverflow.net/help |  |
| https://blender.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://politics.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://chess.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://bricks.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://french.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help | [What are all the different FAQs and Help pages?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/981) |
| https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://android.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://stackapps.com/help |  |
| https://money.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| https://stackoverflow.com/help |  |
| https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help |  |
| (German Language) | [Suggestions for the editable section of the help center](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1131) |
| (Cryptography) | [Let's actually vote on our help-center sections!](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1080) |
| (Parenting) | [Any recent changes to editable sections of the Help Center?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1363) |
| (Science Fiction & Fantasy) | [Editing the Tour and Help Centre](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13452) |